# How to run parallel Aggregators in Spring Integration?

Tags: parallel-processing, spring-integration, enterprise-integration

I'd like to run a Spring Integration flow where I can easily scale up instances of components if capacity of any is reached.

In particular, I wonder how to scale Aggregators in a following scenario: Various components right before the Aggregator layer produce different parts of objects of class X - let's say they produce parts of two such objects X<sub>1</sub>, X<sub>2</sub> - parts are called {a<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>} and {a<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>}, respectively. The Aggregators should now construct X<sub>1</sub> and X<sub>2</sub> from their parts and send them on. Let's also assume there's two Aggregators, A<sub>1</sub> and A<sub>2</sub>.

[image]

**How can I set it up most easily so that it works as expected, i.e. X<sub>1</sub> and X<sub>2</sub> are created and sent off?**

I see the following considerations:

- A<sub>1</sub> gets a<sub>1</sub>, A<sub>2</sub> gets b<sub>1</sub>, and X<sub>1</sub> can't be constructed without something extra here.
- We want some load balancing, which was the reason for multiple Aggregators in the first place.
- Extra Aggregators should be easily added if needed - static configuration of number of Aggregators is to be avoided.

---

I wonder if the following will work for me - this is based on Spring Integration docs, but I'm not sure if I got it all right.

1. Set up a [Redis Message Store](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/redis.html#redis-message-store), where parts of X<sub>1</sub> and X<sub>2</sub> will be stored before all are available.
2. Share the Message Store between all the Aggregator instances. This is setting (6) in the [Aggregator configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator-config).
3. (As usual for an Aggregator) Tag the parts (a's and b's) of the same X with the same CORRELATION_ID. Write ReleaseStrategy based on both a and b having been received.
4. Create a [Redis Lock Registry](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/redis.html#redis-lock-registry) and configure all Aggregators to use it. This is setting (20) in the [Aggregator configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator-config).

Will this do? In particular:

1. Can I share a MessageStore between multiple Aggregators?
2. When sharing a MessageStore, if A<sub>1</sub> writes a<sub>1</sub> into it and A<sub>2</sub> writes b<sub>1</sub>, will my ReleaseStrategy see that X<sub>1</sub> is now ready to be assembled?
3. Will only one Aggregator process the aggregation using the ReleaseStrategy and send off the assembled X, because I'm using locks?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will work, but you don't need Redis, unless you need persistence or your aggregators are running on different boxes (but see below for that); you can share the same `SimpleMessageStore` between the aggregators. By default, each aggregator uses its own in-memory `SimpleMessageStore`.

And, yes, locks (by `correlationId`) ensure only one aggregator will process a group at the same time.

> ... because I'm using locks ...

The aggregator uses its own locks internally, you don't need to lock anything yourself. In fact, with a global `LockRegistry` (gemfire, redis, custom implementation), and a persistent message group store (redis etc), your aggregators can run on different JVMs.